# Total Processing Time for Spring Weflux Rest API(Annotated Controllers)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

We are getting started in Spring Webflux and we are using Annotated Controllers for REST API. We would like to measure the total time the Spring boot server takes to process a request. Looks like we could use Spring [WebFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebFilter.html) however I am not sure how to set StartTime (some kind of attribute in [ServerWebExchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ServerWebExchange.html) or other request headers)? Also once the response is completed how could we get the startTime and calculate the time difference ?

Thanks!

Comment: Write a filter, note start time, call chain.doFilter(...), and at last record end time, thats it

Comment: okay ,trying find good documentation of WebFilter you suggestion?

Comment: @HemantPatel Unfortunately, `WebFilter` class is different from its Spring MVC counterpart, which is not OPs question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `WebFilter` for this. See the example code below:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RequestTimingFilter implements WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return chain.filter(exchange)
            .doOnSuccess(aVoid ->
                log.info("Elapsed Time: {}ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis)
            );
    }
}
```

Note the `doOnSuccess` call, which is only executed when the request is successful. For errors, you can add `doOnError` call to see the request time.